# Lenovo Thinkpad L380 Yoga or Asus Zenbook UX430?

Tags: laptop

Hi!

What do you think about the series lenovo thinkpad? I want to buy a new laptop. I have a good PC at the work. A laptop is an additional computer. Sometimes, I may use it at work (ASP.NET, C#). Now, I'm choosing from 2 models: **Lenovo Thinkpad L380 yoga** and **Asus Zenbook UX430**. I think, that me will have enough of their performance.

I saw a zenbook and I liked it. But some people said, that Thinkpads better, but it's a L-series, but not the T or X.

Lenovo - https://www.informatique.nl/185248/lenovo-thinkpad-yoga-l380-20m5-laptop.html

Asus - https://www.dateks.lv/en/cenas/portativie-datori/157603_asus_zenbook-ux430ua-gv259r-royal-blue-14-fhd-ips-core-i5-8250u-8gb-256gb-ssd-windows-10-pro

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technologically, these machines are effectively identical.  I think the Zenbook as a slightly larger case and display area, but that's it.  I'd lean to the Zenbook, both for aesthetics and the fact I'm familiar with ASUS's excellent warranty service.

Comment: Yes, zenbook is a very aesthetics laptop and it's impressive